# EROR when trying to download pygame on to python

Tags: python, pip, pygame

I've tried lots of different ways of installing pygame and none work it always comes up with an error message.
I need this module for a game: I'm trying to make a multiplayer game for a project for school and online told me to use this module.
Any help would be great!! Also I've never put a question on here before so hope I'm doing it right! Thanks

```
C:\Users\RDSTw>py -m pip install pygame==2.0.0.dev6
Collecting pygame==2.0.0.dev6
  Using cached pygame-2.0.0.dev6.tar.gz (3.7 MB)
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'C:\Python\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\RDSTw\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-lgh1zxp0\\pygame\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\RDSTw\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-lgh1zxp0\\pygame\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\RDSTw\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-ov5fgttm'
         cwd: C:\Users\RDSTw\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-lgh1zxp0\pygame\
    Complete output (31 lines):


    WARNING, No "Setup" File Exists, Running "buildconfig/config.py"
    Using WINDOWS configuration...

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\RDSTw\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-lgh1zxp0\pygame\setup.py", line 258, in <module>
        buildconfig.config.main(AUTO_CONFIG)
      File "C:\Users\RDSTw\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-lgh1zxp0\pygame\buildconfig\config.py", line 208, in main
        deps = CFG.main(**kwds)
      File "C:\Users\RDSTw\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-lgh1zxp0\pygame\buildconfig\config_win.py", line 559, in main
        and download_win_prebuilt.ask(**download_kwargs):
      File "C:\Users\RDSTw\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-lgh1zxp0\pygame\buildconfig\download_win_prebuilt.py", line 269, in ask
        update(x86=x86, x64=x64, sdl2=sdl2)
      File "C:\Users\RDSTw\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-lgh1zxp0\pygame\buildconfig\download_win_prebuilt.py", line 252, in update
        download_prebuilts(download_dir, x86=x86, x64=x64, sdl2=sdl2)
      File "C:\Users\RDSTw\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-lgh1zxp0\pygame\buildconfig\download_win_prebuilt.py", line 101, in download_prebuilts
        download_sha1_unzip(url, checksum, temp_dir, 1)
      File "C:\Users\RDSTw\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-lgh1zxp0\pygame\buildconfig\download_win_prebuilt.py", line 17, in download_sha1_unzip
        import requests
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'
    Making dir :prebuilt_downloads:

    ---
    For help with compilation see:
        https://www.pygame.org/wiki/CompileWindows
    To contribute to pygame development see:
        https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
    ---
    
    ----------------------------------------
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: It's weird that it's doing that. It seems like it is trying to download dependencies. You seem to be on windows, so there should be a prebuilt wheel. Maybe you are on python 3.9? P.S. Pygame is at 2.0.0.dev14 now.

Comment: Please give more details of your Python version, and venv etc.

Answer (score 0):

This says that you don't have the `requests` module installed. So first install `requests` using `pip install -U requests` and then again install `pygame`. I also did it this way.

Comment: I'm using python 3.9 not sure what 2.0.0.dev14 means. I tried to do what you said but it still came up with the same error messages